# three20 and xcode4.3 : lexical or preprocessor issue file not found 

Tags: header, three20, xcode4.3

I am using Xcode 4.3 and iOS 5.1.
I have add three20 to my project successfully. but I encounter 2 issues:

1- ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Projects/iphone/myProj/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos

2- file not found when I import "Three20/TTStyleSheet.h" and other header file

I have added these

- $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../three20
- $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../three20
- three20/Build/Products/three20
  to header search paths as well.

I am using Xcode 4.3 and iOS 5.1.

any suggestion to fix theses 2 issues.
thanks

**Edit** : warning was coursed by Library Search Paths which used to mention three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos   by deleting that I have no warning. But I still have the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out it was a stupid mistake that I did and import directly header files (like  "`Three20/TTStyleSheet.h`" ) to my classes instead of importing "`Three20/three20.h`"

Answer (score 0):

Also, TTStyleSheet.h is within a folder called Three20Style. So you must do:

```
#import 'Three20Style/TTStyleSheet.h'
```

if you want only that header file to be included.